# Can't subscripe to cache service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I try to access the cached data in my pipe but always get the following error:

```ts
Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

the service:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class FormDataService {

  private apiUrl = "http://localhost";
  private data:any;
  private observable: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private _http: Http
  ){}

  getCountries() {
    if(this.data) {
      console.log("data available");
      return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else if(this.observable) {
      console.log("request pending")
      return this.observable;
    } else {
      console.log("request data");
      this.observable = this._http.get(this.apiUrl + "/country")
        .map(res => {
          console.log("data received");
          this.observable = null;
          this.data = res.json();
        });
    }
  }
```

the pipe:

```ts
export class ResolvePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    public _formDataService: FormDataService
  ) {}

  transform(value: number, args: any[]): any {
    return this._formDataService.getCountries().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

I have another question:

the api returns an array of objects

```ts
[{id:1,label:"USA",id:2, label:"DE", ...}]
```

The Pipe should replace the id (value) with the label...where would you do this? In service or pipe?

Edit:

```ts
formdata.service.ts:27 request data
formdata.service.ts:30 data received
formdata.service.ts:27 request data
formdata.service.ts:24 request pending (822 times)
formdata.service.ts:30 data received
```

Comment: you can't subscribe to an object that doesn't exist. instantiate the object first, then try "subscribe" (thats what the error message means)

Answer (score 2):

There is a return missing

```ts
  getCountries() {
    if(this.data) {
      console.log("data available");
      return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else if(this.observable) {
      console.log("request pending")
      return this.observable;
    } else {
      console.log("request data");
      this.observable = this._http.get(this.apiUrl + "/country")
        .map(res => {
          console.log("data received");
          this.observable = null;
          this.data = res.json();
        });
      return this.observable; // <<<<
    }
  }
```

otherwise `null` will be returned and `null` doesn't provide a `subscribe` method.

Comment: thank you! I also add share() ...any idea why the request fires 2 times? I expect only one request. I update the first post with the log.

Comment: The observable will be executed as often as it is subscribed to. I'd also expect it to be executed only once with `share()`.